# get connection with singleton pattern

Tags: java, jdbc, singleton

My task is to get connection with jdbc using singleton pattern. I wanted to ask whether I am using the pattern or not?

```
public class DbUtils {
    private static Connection conn = null;
    static {
        final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library";
        final String  USER = "root";
        final String PASS = "12345";
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        System.out.println("Connected to database");
    }
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. This is a bad idea, as it will not be possible to recover from connection failures.

Comment: This is not a Singleton, nothing prevents people from creating multiple instances (except maybe running out of database connections). A Singleton will have a private constructor in addition to the static `get...` method. That said, don't use Singletons. They tend do get in the way of testing, even if you avoid doing the work in a `static` block.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite a singleton object. In the singleton pattern you're calling a single instance of the object, whereas with this use of a static class you aren't really dealing with an instance.

Larger issues with the implementation:

1. You can't really close a connection. If you do close it, you won't be able to reopen it.
2. `catch (SQLException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }` makes it difficult to recover from connection failures.

You want something more like:

```
public class DbConnection {

    private static DbConnection instance = null;
    private Connection conn = null;

    private DbConnection() {}

    private void init() throws SQLException {
        final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library";
        final String USER = "root";
        final String PASS = "12345";
        
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        System.out.println("Connected to database");
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return conn;
    }

    public static Connection getInstance() throws SQLException {
        if (instance != null && !instance.getConnection().isClosed()) {
            return instance;
        } else {
            instance = new DbConnection();
            instance.init();
        }
    }
}
```

The `private DbConnection() {}` overrides the default public constructor, meaning other classes won't be able to create a new instance of your class. The class maintains a single reference to an instance.

The check for `!instance.getConnection().isClosed()` makes sure that you return a new instance if the previous connection was closed.